# How to fix subquery to stop LEFT JOIN from inflating counts?

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery, left-join

I have two tables: `canvass` and `survey`. Below is a sample schema of each -- the IDs match and each have some purposeful duplicates.

**canvass table**:

```
ID  Name              Result        ContactedBy DateContacted ContactType
1   Seinfeld, Jerry   Contacted     Bluth, Gob     3/5/15   Phone
2   Benes, Elaine     Wrong Address Bluth, Gob     4/7/15   Walk
3   Costanza, George  Contacted     Bluth, Michael 9/15/15  Walk
4   Kramer, Cosmo     Contacted     Funke, Tobias  12/14/14 Walk
5   David, Larry      Contacted     Bluth, Michael 11/11/14 Walk
6   Puddy, David      Not Home      Bluth, Michael 4/9/15   Walk
7   Ross, Susan       Not Home      Funke, Tobias  4/19/15  Phone
1   Seinfeld, Jerry   Contacted     Bluth, Gob     9/15/15  Walk
9   Costanza, Frank   Not Home      Funke, Tobias  3/30/15  Walk
10  Cohen, Ruthie     Call Back     Funke, Tobias  12/3/12  Phone
```

**survey table**:

```
ID  Name             SurveyId   DateContacted ContactType   ContactedBy
1   Seinfeld, Jerry  99         3/5/15        Phone         Bluth, Gob
2   Benes, Elaine    99         4/7/15        Walk          Bluth, Gob
3   Costanza, George 99         9/15/15       Walk          Bluth, Michael
4   Kramer, Cosmo    88         12/14/14      Walk          Funke, Tobias
5   David, Larry     99         11/11/14      Walk          Bluth, Michael
6   Puddy, David     88         4/9/15        Walk          Bluth, Michael
7   Ross, Susan      11         4/19/15       Phone         Funke, Tobias
1   Seinfeld, Jerry  99         9/15/15       Walk          Bluth, Gob
9   Costanza, Frank  99         3/30/15       Walk          Funke, Tobias
10  Cohen, Ruthie    11         12/3/12       Phone         Funke, Tobias
```

My tables are way larger and messier than the two above, but it should give an idea. Here's a quick example of how I'd like the results to look (even though I'm not getting it with the query below):

```
ContactedBy    Knocked    Contacted     88 SurveyID 99 SurveyID
Bluth, Gob     30           3               3              0
Bluth, Michael 40           3               2              1
Funke, Tobias  10           2               1              1
```

If I run the counts separately (whether it all be together in one query or if I use subqueries) by table, I get the correct results -- but if I try to put them together in one, all of the counts get very inflated because of the `LEFT JOIN`. I know that it's because people have more surveys than just the ones I care about, which duplicates the amount of each ID -- but I can't quite figure out how to stop it.

This is my best shot at a query -- though like I said above -- even though it's querying and producing results similar to the hoped-for table above, it's over-inflating all the counts:

```
SELECT a.contactedby, SUM(Knocked), SUM(Contacted), SUM(88), SUM(99)
FROM (SELECT c.id cid,
    c.contactedby,
    c.result,
    c.contacttype,
    c.datecontacted,
    COUNT(c.id) Knocked,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c.result = "Contacted" THEN c.id ELSE NULL END) Contacted,
    s.id sid,
    s.surveyid,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 88 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END) 88,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.surveyid = 99 THEN s.id ELSE NULL END) 99
    FROM canvass c
    LEFT JOIN survey s ON s.id = c.id AND RIGHT(s.datecontacted,2)="15" AND s.contacttype = "Walk" AND s.contactedby = c.contactedby
    WHERE RIGHT(c.datecontacted,2)="15" AND c.contacttype = "Walk"
    GROUP BY c.id, c.contactedby
    ORDER BY c.contactedby
) AS a
GROUP BY a.contactedby;
```

Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated! The end-game is getting those results about the surveys I care about from a query while ignoring anything in either table that wasn't acquired from a walk in 2015.

--

I tried another query based on the helpful [GROUPing pitfall](http://wikido.isoftdata.com/index.php/The_GROUPing_pitfall) article posted below, and though I get no errors and the results are in the exact form I want and the knocked/contacted numbers are good, the 88 and 99 surveys are mostly `NULL`s with a few random numbers populated. This is the query:

```
SELECT c.contactedby contby, COUNT(CASE WHEN c.id IS NOT NULL THEN c.id ELSE NULL END) Knocked, COUNT(CASE WHEN c.result = "Contacted" THEN c.id ELSE NULL END) Contacted, s.88, s.99
FROM canvass c
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT s1.id sid, s1.contactedby contby1, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s1.surveyid = 88 THEN s1.id ELSE NULL END) 88, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s1.surveyid = 99 THEN s1.id ELSE NULL END) 99
        FROM survey s1
        GROUP BY contby1
    ) AS s ON s.sid = c.id
WHERE RIGHT(c.datecontacted,2) = "15" AND c.contacttype = "Walk"
```

Answer (score 2):

The short version: you can't aggregate two tables at once in the same query.

You'll want to write two subqueries that group by whatever you want to be unique in your main query, and then join them together.

For a slightly longer and more thorough explanation that I wrote for my coworkers a while back, read this article on the [GROUPing Pitfall](http://wikido.isoftdata.com/index.php/The_GROUPing_pitfall) - the problem you've run into.  It has query examples and everything!

Comment: Bahh! Thanks. Better than trying to make this work for another few hours to no avail. Is it possible you could provide a bit more of an explanation on who to write two subqueries that are grouped together by my main query? I don't know that I've done a sub-sub-query before.

Comment: I actually wrote that article on the GROUPing Pitfall, and it's as clear as I can make it.  It has query examples and everything. Check it out!

Comment: One last question after reading your article: am I out of luck if these two tables have a many-to-many relationship? In the two described above, each person/id has multiple rows because they've mostly all been knocked/canvassed many times and they've mostly all answered multiple surveys. Their primary keys obviously match up -- but your article made it seem like I might be in trouble if it's not one-to-many.

Comment: @Ryan so the trick is that your result, your final query, is going to be unique on Some Thing.  It doesn't matter what the relationship between your two tables is, as long as when you write those subqueries, you can make sure that you're grouping by that Some Thing.

As long as your subqueries can group by the something that makes their rows unique for the purpose of your final query, you're good (because then you can join them into your main query using that value).

Comment: Thanks -- I attempted a new query with your advice, but I couldn't quite get it. I posted the query above if you get a chance to check it out.

Comment: Checkout http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases maybe?